# Algorithms for searching all possible combinations of a set of data

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm currently playing a game where you have 5 armor slots to equip armor pieces. Each of these armor pieces themselves have 'slots' for skills with varying points - an arm piece could have +3 points of Skill A, and +5 points of Skill B for example. When you accumulate at least 10 points of a skill you will activate it for use.

As an exercise I'd like to make a program that, given a database of all the armor pieces, then given a list of criteria (e.g. I'd like to have Skill A, Skill B, Skill C in this set) will give a set of all possible armor combinations which result in having these skills for use e.g.

Equip 
Head piece A for +2 to skill A
Chest piece A for +5 to skill A, +2 to skill C

etc..

OR

Equip
Head piece B for +5 to skill A, +2 to skill B
Chest piece A for for +5 to skill A, +2 to skill C

etc...

What algorithms, techniques and considerations should I take into account when making this? I plan to make this in C# along with a standalone database of some sort.

Comment: If your item list is not staggeringly huge, you could, upon being instructed to find items to give you skill X Y and Z, load from the database into memory all items that give any X Y or Z at all, order by how much X+Y+Z they give descending and then do the cartesian product starting at the top of each slot's collection and gradually moving your way down until you've found enough satisfying combinations. I want to think more about this but I'm about to go to bed, if you still need an answer when I wake up I'll come back to this :)

Comment: I'm estimating the item list to be at least 1000 items, so it'll be fairly large, but not staggeringly so. I'll give this a shot, thanks!